Calculating Customer Lifetime in Google Data Studio aka Looker Studio
I have a transactions table with columns that matter are Date, Customer ID and Purchase Amount. I want to use that to calculate customer life time value. I want to apply the below logic
Customer Lifetime Value = number of months between max date and min date for any customer
How can I achieve that in Looker Studio given that Looker Studio does not allow to create new summary tables?
